# Structuring an eclipse project containing multiple git repositories

Tags: git, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, egit

I'm using Eclipse CDT and egit and I need to construct a single project from multiple repositories. One contains the main body of the source code and the other contains utility scripts used as part of the build process (which are also used when building several other projects).

I'm struggling to understand if I can make egit work sensibly with this setup. I can't work out how to associate a CDT project with more than one git repository and that means that I can't perform VCS operations for some of the files in the project.

I'd like to be able to right click on any file in the workspace and have egit work out which repository it is in and so perform operations (history, blame...) correctly. Has anybody managed to do this or can you point me at documentation I can't find because of the huge number of "Multiple projects in a single repo" guides.

Comment: What is the problem with having just multiple projects (one for each repository)? In Eclipse in general, it's not really possible to have a project consisting of multiple source locations. You can link resources, but that's limited.

Comment: Users with multiple projects might/will need to have a set of build scripts for each project (they might need to make changes whilst working on one project that are not yet needed in another). The users want to avoid having two projects for each thing they work on (foo + foo_scripts, bar + bar_scripts...)

Comment: @robinst The repositories have been pulled into the same folder if the project is in .../project/ then the two repos are at .../project/foo/.git and .../project/scripts/.git

Comment: But the above project setup would mean that project files (.project, .classpath, etc) are not in the repository – and they should be. In addition, EGit can only have 1 repository associated with a project, and the project needs to be inside that repository. So I recommend having multiple projects.

Comment: @robinst Care to expand that "Egit can only have 1 repository associated with a project" to an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Ok, done (with a few examples).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EGit can only have 1 repository associated with a project, and the project needs to be inside that repository. For example, the following are valid layouts.

On the same level as the project:

```
.git
.project
src
...
```

Containing more than one project:

```
.git
project-a
    .project
project-b
    project
```

It's not possible to have something like this and have EGit know about the repository for this project:

```
.project
foo
    .git
```

The above would also mean that project files (.project, .classpath, etc) are not in the repository – and they should be.

So I recommend having multiple projects, one (or more than one) for each repository.

Comment: Nice clear answer, but some authoritative source would make it so much better. (Though I'm afraid that that's asking for too much, given how bad are Eclipse's docs...)

Answer (score 3):

In April 2016, [EGit 4.3 introduced support for nested repositories](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/technology.egit/releases/4.3). Eclipse 4.6 Neon, introduced on June 2016, includes EGit 4.4.

Nested repositories are detected automatically; just use the Team->Share Project contextual menu in the project tree node.